# Запретить col переход на новую строку блоку, а то что внутри блока, чтоб не изменилось

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть вот такая проблема. у меня есть

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
             <div>Какой-то текст</div>
             <div>Еще какой-то длинный текст</div>                 
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Мне нужно, чтоб при изменении масштаба экрана мой div card не менял размер и не переходил на новую строку. Это можно сделать с помощью 
`display: "inline - block"` и `whiteSpace: "nowrap"`, но при таком варианте использования у меня и то, что в div card становится inline - block. А мне нужно, чтоб оно не менялось.

[image: Как видите текст поехал]
Как видите текст поехал. 
Если ближе к моему коду то вот:

```
<div className="row"
  style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap", display: "inline-block" }}>
  {card.map((k, i) => (
    <div className="card col" key={i} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>          
     <div className="description-info">{k["title"]}</div>
     <div>{k["subtitle"]}</div>
     <Button className="mt-auto p-2">Подробнее</Button>
   </div>
   ))}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно, зачем стили писать в html?

Это как минимум не читаемо!

```
.card {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Не съезжает, но изменяет размеры card, нужно, чтоб было бы как на скрине, но текст был в ней

Comment: position: absolute для card